# What is the correct syntax to access an array of array references with for/foreach

Tags: perl, for-loop, reference

Given:

```
my @main_array = ();

my @sub_array1 = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
my @sub_array2 = ( "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" );

push @main_array, \@sub_array1;
push @main_array, \@sub_array2;
print "size of main_array is ",scalar(@main_array),"\n";
```

I want to foreach through the main_array and
then foreach through the two arrays that it contains
I have no idea what the syntax is for that.

Don't know if this is correct, but Perl seems to want a $ in the front of the
foreach variable here. (doesn't like @$sub_array)
I would also like to know the syntax to for loop through the main and sub as well.

```
foreach my $sub_array (@main_array)
{
   print $sub_array; # prints ARRAY(0x213232)
   # loop through each item in sub array
   #foreach ... 
}
```

Edit: So to summarize the answers given below (thanks to all):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @main_array = ();

my @sub_array1 = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
my @sub_array2 = ( "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" );

push @main_array, \@sub_array1;
push @main_array, \@sub_array2;
print "size of main_array is ",scalar(@main_array),"\n";

print "--------foreach ---------------------\n";

foreach my $sub_array (@main_array)
{
   print "Sub array has ", scalar(@{$sub_array})," elements\n";
   foreach my $value ( @{$sub_array})
   {
      print "value: ",$value,"\n";
   }
}

print "--------------- for ----------------------- \n";

for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@main_array); $i++)
{
    my $sub_array = $main_array[$i];
    print "Sub array has ", scalar( @{$sub_array}), " elements\n";
    for (my $j = 0; $j < scalar( @{$sub_array}); $j++)
    {
       print "value: ", $sub_array->[$j],"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `for my $v (@$sub_array) { .. }`

Comment: You are storing array references in your main array. So in your loop your variable `$sub_array` is an array reference.

Answer (score 6):

```
my $sz = 0;
for my $outer (@main_array) {
  for my $inner( @{ $outer } ) {
     print $inner;
     $sz++;
    }
  }

print "total number of all values held in main_array is $sz \n";
```

perllol and perldsc are good sources of info on these matters

For debugging `use Data::Dumper;  print Dumper(\@main_array)` is useful

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for  the reply - if I do foreach my $value ( @{$sub_array})   {  print $value,"\n"; } it prints 4 values for each inner array, whereas they both have 5 values. How would you access a single element of the inner array?

Comment: using your example data ``print $main_array[0]->[1]`` gives ``2`` and ``print $main_array[1]->[1]`` gives ``b``.  Please read perldsc and perllol, they explain it better than I can!

Comment: @Scooter Edit your question to show the exact code you're using that only prints 4 out of 5 array elements. The code Vorsprung gave  prints all values in each inner array, so you must be doing something different. `perl -wE 'my @array = ([1..5],["a".."e"]); foreach my $outer (@array) { foreach my $inner (@$outer) { say $inner } }'`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Sorry, my bad. the first element was at the end of a previous line and I missed it. They all print.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is traditional nested loops:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @sub_array1 =   ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  );
my @sub_array2 = qw/ a  b  c  d  e  /;
my @main_array = ( \@sub_array1, \@sub_array2 );

print "\@main_array has ", scalar @main_array, " elements.\n\n\n";

foreach my $outer ( @main_array ) {
    print "Sub array has ", scalar @{$outer}, " elements:\t";
    foreach my $inner ( @$outer ) {
        print "($inner) ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
@main_array has 2 elements.


Sub array has 5 elements:   (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) 
Sub array has 5 elements:   (a) (b) (c) (d) (e)
```

To access individual elements directly, you could say:

```
print $main_array[1][3], "\n";
```

...which would produce "`d`".

Or within the outer loop you could do this:

```
for my $outer ( @main_array ) {
    print join( ' ', $outer->[0], $outer->[1], $outer->[2], $outer->[3], $outer->[4] ), "\n";
    # prints first five elements.
}
```

...but that's kind of silly since it's not as flexible as just using an inner loop.

Comment: I assume you chose `print join( ' ', $outer->[0], ...` to illustrate `->` syntax, since it's easier to just dereference: `print join( ' ', @$outer );`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I chose that syntax to illustrate to Scooter the answer to his followup question where he asked, "*How would you access a single element of the inner array?*"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot @Davido - some good points in comments. Nested loops are a basic idiom but they always raise "style" questions for me in `perl`. I think I am going to have ask what might be a duplicate question about them myself.

Comment: @G.Cito There are many times in Perl where an explicit nested loop can be replaced by some other construct that is more idiomatic.  But even `join "\t", @array` is a loop internally.

Comment: @G.Cito If you want to post a question that is more philosophical in nature, it's probably more on-topic on PerlMonks.  Here it would probably just get closed.  There, it would probably provoke worthwhile discussion.

Comment: @DavidO good points and that was more my question ... since many alternatives to loops are loops themselves (`B::Deparse` can show some of this) how does one decide? . Sometimes "nesting" things differently (nested dereferences?) seems more comprehensible  `perl -wE 'my @array = ([1..5],["a".."e", [ "f" .. "z"]]);  say @{ $_->[-1] } for @array  '` For me "style" has become more of a synonym for "readable and self-documenting" and nesting is sometimes hard to mentally parse. I guess I could just code fold it out of sight in my $EDITOR.

Comment: Optimize for the developer's sanity first, then later for specific needs such as run time, runtime space, resource conservation, etc.